# Doctrine order by of 2 joined tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got the following entity structure:
**company -> systemCompanies -> system**

So in particular: company (oneToMany) systemCompany (ManyToOne) system {int id, int position}

Basically a manyToMany company <---> system relation, but I need the middle join table for some extra fields.

And I always need to order by the system position when fetching `$company->getSystemCompanies()`;

So something like:

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'company', targetEntity: SystemCompany::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
#[ORM\OrderBy(['system.position' => 'ASC'])]
private Collection $systemCompanies;
```

which doesn't work (just `#[ORM\OrderBy(['system' => 'ASC'])]` does, sorting by the system_id)

I don't want to write custom repository methods for this if I can avoid it. And doing a custom `usort()`in getSystemCompanies() would be my last choice.

A custom OrderBy on the system.id would also be fine.
Like (raw sql): `ORDER BY system_id = 5 DESC, system_id = 2 DESC, system_id = 3 DESC,...`, but
`#[ORM\OrderBy(['system = 5' => 'DESC', 'system = 2' => 'DESC', ...])]` also doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0):

are you try to set only this?

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'company', targetEntity: SystemCompany::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
#[ORM\OrderBy(['position' => 'ASC'])]
private Collection $systemCompanies;
```

'position' is a field in your SystemCompany class

Comment: no, it's on the system class as the use case is: you edit a company and want to list on which systems it is. Or sometimes just list the systems / use the system in other relations as well.

Comment: So in your SystemCompany entity you have System collection and in this relation you can set position in ASC